# how to substitute tox environment dependencies with considering the Python version?

Tags: python, tox

Suppose that we have two tox environment collections `{py37,py38}-develop` and `{py37,py38}-test`. The `develop` environments dependencies include the corresponding `test` environment dependencies (for simplicity, additional dependencies and configurations of each environment collection is not shown):

```
[tox]
envlist = {py37,py38}-{test,develop}

[testenv:{py37,py38}-test]
deps = pytest
commands = pytest tests

[testenv:{py37,py38}-develop]
deps = {[testenv:py?-test]deps}  # How to describe python version here?
```

The current solution is:

```
[tox]
envlist = {py37,py38}-{test,develop}

[testenv:{py37,py38}-test]
deps = pytest
commands = pytest tests

[testenv:{py37,py38}-develop]
deps = 
    py37: {[testenv:py37-test]deps}
    py38: {[testenv:py38-test]deps}
```

Also, I know that by using the `{envname}` variable we can use the whole environment name, but I cannot extract the `py*` part for using inside dependencies variable substitution.

How to describe this dependency without duplication in the `develop` environment dependencies section? I also prefer the tox configuration to be complete itself and not enforcing the user to pass additional arguments when running tox.

Comment: Does `deps = {[testenv:{py37,py38}-test]deps}` work?

Comment: @sinoroc No. It returns `ERROR: Invalid requirement: '{[testenv:{py37,py38}-test]deps}'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of the @sinoroc answer, I found that the factor conditions are evaluated on the actual executing environment (not the environment that contains it).

For example:

```
[tox]
envlist = {py37,py38}-{test,develop}

[testenv:{py37,py38}-test]
deps = 
    py37: dep1
    py38: dep2

[testenv:{py37,py38}-develop]
deps = {[testenv:py37-test]deps}  # The py37 here is not important.
```

Works successfully independent of `py*` factor specified in substitution line. Actually, the substitution mechanism copies the whole `deps` variable including the factors. So, the factors are evaluated on the actual running environment (not the included one).

Finally, in order to clear up the ambiguity of the `py37` factor used in the `develop` environment, I added `pyauto` factor in the `test` environment (which is not included in the `envlist`, so, the user cannot run it):

```
[tox]
envlist = {py37,py38}-{test,develop}

[testenv:{py37,py38,pyauto}-test]
deps = 
    py37: dep1
    py38: dep2

[testenv:{py37,py38}-develop]
deps = {[testenv:pyauto-test]deps}
```

The solution is similar to @sinoroc solution, but:

1. It does not append an additional section.
2. In the case of many dependency inclusions, it's more simple and does not need many sections that use `common*` naming pattern.

As a side note, you can also include `pyauto` factor in the `envlist` in order to allow the user to run the `pyauto-...` environments directly which means that it selects the Python version automatically. But if there is any factor condition like `py38: ...`, the tox evaluates its condition to `false` even if the automatically selected Python version is 3.8 (actually, the tox considers the factor in the conditions, not the python version). In this case, you can use [PEP-508](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/#id7) dependency specification instead of factor conditions (that tox [supports it](https://tox.wiki/en/latest/config.html#conf-deps)).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like that:

```
[tox]
envlist = {py37,py38}-{test,develop}

[common]
deps =
  py37: CommonLib<2
  py38: CommonLib>=2

[testenv:{py37,py38}-test]
deps =
  {[common]deps}
  TestOnlyLib

[testenv:{py37,py38}-develop]
deps =
  {[common]deps}
  DevOnlyLib
```